# Multiple apps under 1 google account when using Google Translate API?

Tags: key, google-translate, fee

How to define the service fee between different apps under 1 google account when using Google Translate API?
I have more than one game in my Google Developer Console account, and it seems that they share the same account of Google Translate API. So how could I know how much does each of them cost?

Comment: Track it yourself.

Comment: Track the logs...